# Vue.js pass callback through a prop.

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <pagination class="center" :pagination="pagination" :callback="loadData" :options="paginationOptions"></pagination>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Pagination from 'vue-bootstrap-pagination';

    export default {
        components: { Pagination },

        props: ['pagination', 'loadData'],

        data() {
            return {
                paginationOptions: {
                    offset: 5,
                    previousText: 'Terug',
                    nextText: 'Volgende',
                    alwaysShowPrevNext: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In another component I use that ^:

```
<template>
    <pagination :pagination="pagination" :callback="loadData" :options="paginationOptions"></pagination>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   loadData() {
       this.fetchMessages(this.pagination.current_page);
   }

   //fetchMessages
 }
</script>
```

But I receive the error:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "callback". Expected Function, got Undefined. 
(found in component <pagination>)
```

Is it not possible in `Vue.js 2.0` to pass a callback?

Comment: The prop name is `callback`, not `loadData`.

Answer (score 5):

I think your second component may not be written accurately, your `loadData` callback should be in `methods`:

```
<template>
    <pagination :pagination="pagination" :callback="loadData" :options="paginationOptions"></pagination>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   methods: {
     loadData() {
         this.fetchMessages(this.pagination.current_page);
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ request }}</pre>
    <pagination @callback="loadData"></pagination>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Pagination from './Pagination.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { Pagination },
  data() {
    return {
      request: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadData(request) {
      this.request = request
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Pagination.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$emit('callback', { currentPage: 10, whatEver: 7 })">call it back</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Pagination'
  }
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/8xyy4m9kq8

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be better, if you provide more information, like what this code does and how it fixes the problem!